# Stirling number of the second kind

Tags: combinatorics

How to prove this?
$$
{n+1 \brace m+1} = \sum_{k=m}^{n} {n \choose k} {k \brace m}\,.
$$

Comment: I would try induction, but Im not sure. The limits of the sum seem incorrect.

Comment: There is a proof via generating functions [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2002259/evaluate-sum-involving-stirling-numbers-of-second-kind-using-egf).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be 
$${n+1 \brace m+1} = \sum_{k=m}^{n} {n \choose k} {k \brace m}.$$
Combinatorial proof. Note that ${n+1 \brace m+1}$ (the LHS) is the number of ways to partition the set $\{1,2,\dots,n+1\}$ into $m+1$ nonempty subsets.

On the other hand, such partitions can be univocally generated by taking a subset of $n-k$ elements of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ (${n \choose n-k}={n \choose k}$ ways), adding to it the element $(n+1)$ (so this set is non-empty), and then by completing the partition by selecting a partition of $m$ nonempty subsets of the remaining set of $(n+1)-1-(n-k)=k$ elements ($ {k \brace m}$ ways). The number of partitions generated in this way is given by the RHS.

P.S. See also the [wikipage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).