# simplifying a sum containing the binomial coefficient and stirling numbers second kind

Tags: combinatorics, stirling-numbers

I'm working on this sum, I don't have to find out the actual value, I just have to simplify it as much as I can. But the problem is that I don't know how far I can simplify it before reaching the actual arithmetic value so I need help. Here is the sum, where ${n \brace k}$ stands for the Stirling Numbers of second kind:

$$\sum\limits_{i=0}^{30} \binom{30}{i}{i\brace 25}$$

We know that for $n < k$ we have ${n\brace k} = 0$ and ${n\brace n} = 1$ so we can simplify it into the following:

$$\binom{30}{25}+\sum\limits_{i=26}^{30}\binom{30}{i}{i\brace 25}$$

From now on, I don't know how to proceed. I could technically start breaking down the Stirling numbers and eventually get an arithmetic value but that's not quite the sense of the problem and as I'm new into combinatorics, I don't know how far I can simplify it. Any help from more advanced mathematicians is very welcome!

Comment: There are a number of standard identities involving Stirling numbers of the second kind. One of them involves sums of a form very similar to the one you have simplified to...

Comment: Notes on MathJax and $\LaTeX$ typesetting [can be found here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: This is your 5th question today. You really should learn how to use MathJax. It’s really not hard at all. You just use include all your formulas between the dollar signs, for the most part. One can get used to it very quickly.

Comment: For a combinatorial proof, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2003405/stirling-number-of-the-second-kind?noredirect=1&lq=1).