# Stirling number of second kind and binomial coefficients, how to prove equality?

Tags: proof-writing, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions, stirling-numbers

I was told that this equality can be derived easily using exponential generation functions:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{Bmatrix}
n\\  k
\end{Bmatrix}
=\frac{1}{k!}\sum\limits_{i \in [0,k]}(-1)^{k-i}\binom{k}{i}i^n
\end{equation*}

And I would like to know, how to start the proof in similar cases. Please, give me just a little hint.

Comment: Do you want a proof using the generating function OR a combinatorial proof ? ... Both can be found on this site.

Comment: I want a proof using the generating function. Unfortunately, I haven't seen it on this site. I would be grateful, if you could give me a link.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2002293

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exponential generating function for the Stirling numbers of the secod kind is given by
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \begin{Bmatrix}n\\  k \end{Bmatrix} \frac{x^n}{n!} y^k = \operatorname{exp}(y(e^x-1)).
\end{eqnarray*}
So
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1}{n!} \begin{Bmatrix}n\\  k \end{Bmatrix} &=& [x^n] [y^k]:   \operatorname{exp}(y(e^x-1)) \\
&=& [x^n] :   \frac{(e^x-1)^k}{k!} \\
&=& [x^n] :   \frac{1}{k!} \sum_{i=0}^{k} (-1)^{k-i} \binom{k}{i} e^{ix} \\
&=&   \frac{1}{k!} \sum_{i=0}^{k} (-1)^{k-i} \binom{k}{i} \frac{i^n}{n!}. \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Yes. Besides, very neat explanation !

Comment: Thank you for your explanation!